# Why is the article detail page in communities not showing the custom theme layout sections?

Tags: community, knowledge

I have created a custom theme layout type for use in our community, which uses a custom theme layout component. This works fine for custom pages in our community. However, when I assign a custom theme layout to the article detail page, the template sections in the drag and drop interface do not update to the custom ones. However, if I look at the page structure button on the left, they show up in there. I can confirm the custom theme layout is fine, because it works on pages other than the article detail page, and it is a VERY simple custom theme layout. I have taken the code from documentation here - the only difference is the body div is first, not last.  and even tried with no modifications to the code at all:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Sample Custom Theme Layout">
<aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<div>
    <div class="mainContentArea">
        {!v.body}
    </div>
    <div class="searchRegion">
        {!v.search}
    </div>
    <div class="profileMenuRegion">
        {!v.profileMenu}
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
        {!v.navBar}
    </div>
    <div class="newHeader">
        {!v.newHeader}
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been resolved in the Summer 17 release.